# C# SQL ExecuteNonQuery Returns Control Before Query Completes

Tags: c#, sql-server, console

I'm using a C# console application to restore a database nightly.  I have the C# app call a stored procedure to perform the restore using `ExecuteNonQuery`. Then it runs a second stored procedure on the newly restored database.  Sometimes (not always) that second stored procedure fails with the error:

> Database 'dbnamehere' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.

My understanding is that control shouldn't be passed to the second `ExecuteNonQuery` before the first `ExecuteNonQuery` finishes. So, why is this happening? What's the solution for this?

C#

```
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = @"dbnamehere.dbo.sprocDailyRestore";
command.CommandTimeout = 3600;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE dbnamehere SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE dbnamehere 
FROM DISK = 'C:\mypathhere\filename.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'filename' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_Primary_Data.mdf',
     MOVE 'ETLStaging_4D600DAC' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_ETLStaging_Data.mdf',
     MOVE 'RealAnalytics_7AFB9B94' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_Analytics_Data.mdf',
     MOVE 'filename_log' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_Primary_Log.ldf', 
     REPLACE, NORECOVERY;

RESTORE DATABASE dbnamehere 
FROM DISK = 'C:\scheduled-tasks\RealPageDownloader\Repo\filename.diff' 
WITH MOVE 'filename' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_Primary_Data.mdf',
     MOVE 'ETLStaging_4D600DAC' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_ETLStaging_Data.mdf',
     MOVE 'RealAnalytics_7AFB9B94' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_Analytics_Data.mdf',
     MOVE 'filename_log' TO 'C:\MSSQL\Data\dbnamehere_Primary_Log.ldf',
     REPLACE;


ALTER DATABASE dbnamehere SET multi_user;
```

I should note both stored procedures are executed using `ExecuteNonQuery` and both stored procedures live in a different database than the one being restored.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Use `WITH RECOVERY`

Comment: @jarlh yes SQL Server

Comment: @Codexer use WITH RECOVERY on the *.diff restore like this...REPLACE, RECOVERY?

Comment: Yes on second query. Your first query has NORECOVERY which doesnt allow the use of the database.

Comment: [Heres a good thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267073/database-cannot-be-opened-it-is-in-the-middle-of-a-restore) about this.

Comment: @Codexer got the same error using RECOVERY.